# Can this post be completely deleted?

Tags: support, answers

SE had a glitch while I was modifying an answer immediately after first posting it (edits made within the first five minutes don't show up as edits).

For some reason it posted the old answer and another answer.  I deleted it but it still shows up as a deleted post.

Can you moderators [completely wipe out the deleted answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/56138/formant-analysis-frequency-what-makes-a-peak-value/56145#56145)?

Answer (score 1):

Robert, I see that you deleted your answer. As it is right now, it's visible only to you, mods and users with enough of reputation.

You can't really delete it completely. I believe that only SE mods can remove deleted posts in full.

[This page](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) might be of some help.

Comment: that's what i would like you to do, jojek.  the creation of the second post was literally a glitch done by SE **while** i was modifying my answer 30 seconds after first posting it.  but it was **me** that deleted it, but i would like to see it completely gone, if it isn't too difficult with you admins with admin tools to do it.

Comment: Like I said, DSP mods most likely can't do it. I contacted someone in upper hierarchy.

Comment: thank you jojek.  they should arm you with sufficient power to delete a **"bad"** post (whatever the "badness" is).

Comment: From what I understand, SE tries to keep a history of all changes. Will have a look.

Comment: an **internal* history is good, to keep you moderators honest.  but it should be possible for an admin to (with the exception of the *internal history* that only moderators/admins can see) totally blow away a bad or useless answer.  what if i started posting obscene racist diatribe crap?  you don't want "users with enough reputation" to see it, even if it is in a grey box.

Comment: In such cases Community Team would handle it. Meanwhile, I would edit the post to remove the content, lock it and leave deleted.

Comment: do you want me do edit the deleted post or are you doing it?

Comment: Already done ;)

Comment: I updated my answer with yet another link. A suggested action is disassociation. I will keep asking for better solution.

Comment: Thanks @jojek! For some reason, I didn't see rb-j's question until now.

Answer (score 0):

It is deleted.

This is as deleted as things ever get on Stack Exchange. Even "[obscene racist diatribe crap](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/hey-peter-or-someone-can-you-fix-this#comment1111_1636)" only gets deleted to this degree, though content flagged as spam or offensive is hidden behind a content warning, not merely greyed out. The only other deletion option is removing it entirely from the database and we don't do that unless it's absolutely necessary. I don't have a count but I'd guess that the total number of posts removed from the database is extremely small, possibly in the single digits... possibly three or fewer.

I'm not sure why this bug happened and if it occurs again, please post a bug report so that we can look into it but hard deleting the extra post isn't a solution to it. Even clearing the content isn't necessary. The post existing isn't going to harm you in any way and there's only 16 people on the site who can see it as of right now.

Comment: thank you.  all i can say is while i was editing the post (a minute after first posting it, simply to add a sentence i forgot to say), i got a message that said another answer was being posted.  i had presumed it was another answer from another person.  but when i hit **Save Edits**, the other post was my own original post.  of course i do not know the source of the glitch.  i would be more inclined to post on the general Meta page a bug report, but you guys ain't very friendly to me over there.